# Comparing and removing object from ArrayLists using Java 8

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream

My apologies if this is a simple basic info that I should be knowing. This is the first time I am trying to use Java 8 streams and other features.

I have two ArrayLists containing same type of objects. Let's say `list1` and `list2`. Let's say the lists has Person objects with a property "**employeeId**".

The scenario is that I need to merge these lists. However, `list2` may have some objects that are same as in `list1`. So I am trying to remove the objects from `list2` that are same as in `list1` and get a result list that then I can merge in `list1`.

I am trying to do this with Java 8 **removeIf()** and **stream()** features. Following is my code:

```
public List<PersonDto> removeDuplicates(List<PersonDto> list1, List<PersonDto> list2) {
        List<PersonDto> filteredList = list2.removeIf(list2Obj -> {
            list1.stream()
                .anyMatch( list1Obj -> (list1Obj.getEmployeeId() == list2Obj.getEmployeeId()) );
        } );
    }
```

The above code is giving compile error as below:

**The method removeIf(Predicate) in the type Collection is not applicable for the arguments (( list2Obj) -> {})**

So I changed the `list2Obj` at the start of "**removeIf()**" to `(<PersonDto> list2Obj)` as below:

```
public List<PersonDto> removeDuplicates(List<PersonDto> list1, List<PersonDto> list2) {
            List<PersonDto> filteredList = list2.removeIf((<PersonDto> list2Obj) -> {
                list1.stream()
                    .anyMatch( list1Obj -> (list1Obj.getEmployeeId() == list2Obj.getEmployeeId()) );
            } );
        }
```

This gives me an error as below:

**Syntax error on token "<", delete this token** for the '**<**' in `(<PersonDto> list2Obj)` and **Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)** for the part from '**-> {**'

I am at loss on what I really need to do to make it work.

Would appreciate if somebody can please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your function just a little bit to make it more readable:

```
public static List<PersonDto> removeDuplicates(List<PersonDto> left, List<PersonDto> right) {
    left.removeIf(p -> {
        return right.stream().anyMatch(x -> (p.getEmployeeId() == x.getEmployeeId()));
    });
    return left;
}
```

Also notice that you are modifying the `left` parameter, you are not creating a new `List`.

You could also use: `left.removeAll(right)`, but you need `equals` and `hashcode` for that and it seems you don't have them; or they are based on something else than `employeeId`.

Another option would be to collect those lists to a `TreeSet` and use `removeAll`:

```
TreeSet<PersonDto> leftTree = left.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(PersonDto::getEmployeeId))));

TreeSet<PersonDto> rightTree = right.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(PersonDto::getEmployeeId))));

leftTree.removeAll(rightTree);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, appreciated! I wasn't aware of `removeAll()` but you are right the `equals` and `hashcode` are based on something else. In you code, what is the first `return` returning? I mean, I know it's to return the filtered list but the placement of `return` keyword is throwing me off. I would think that first `return` before `left.removeIf(...`. The second `return` is returning the original list when there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Gauzy `removeIf` takes a `Predicate` as input; thus that returns a `boolean`.

Comment: Eugene, Hi! In your second snippet, I think you don't need to stream the lists in order to create the `TreeSet`s. Just create the `TreeSet`s with the comparator, and then call `addAll` with each list.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner hey! that would indeed merge them, but the OP wanted `So I am trying to remove the objects from list2 that are same as in list1`, so I guess it really depends on what the OP *actually* needs

Comment: @Eugene Sure, I understand. But still, you can do `TreeSet set1 = new TreeSet(comparator); set1.addAll(list1); TreeSet set2 = new TreeSet(comparator); set2.addAll(list2); set1.removeAll(set2);`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner first its *really* hard to type your name from the phone :) second, yes, could be done like this too

Comment: @Eugene hahaha, just Fede is OK

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are trying to merge both lists without duplicating the elements that belong to the *intersection*. There are many ways to do this. One is the way you've tried, i.e. remove elements from one list that belong to the other, then merge. And this, in turn, can be done in several ways.

One of these ways would be to keep the employee ids of one list in a `HashSet` and then use `removeIf` on the other list, with a predicate that checks whether each element has an employee id that is contained in the set. This is better than using `anyMatch` on the second list for each element of the first list, because `HashSet.contains` runs in `O(1)` amortized time. Here's a sketch of the solution:

```
// Determine larger and smaller lists
boolean list1Smaller = list1.size() < list2.size();
List<PersonDto> smallerList = list1Smaller ? list1 : list2;
List<PersonDto> largerList = list1Smaller ? list2 : list1;

// Create a Set with the employee ids of the larger list
// Assuming employee ids are long
Set<Long> largerSet = largerList.stream()
    .map(PersonDto::getEmployeeId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// Now remove elements from the smaller list
smallerList.removeIf(dto -> largerSet.contains(dto.getEmployeeId()));
```

The logic behind this is that `HashSet.contains` will take the same time for both a large and a small set, because it runs in `O(1)` amortized time. However, traversing a list and removing elements from it will be faster on smaller lists.

Then, you are ready to merge both lists:

```
largerList.addAll(smallerList);
```

Comment: The set of employee ids surely hasn’t the type `Set<PersonDto>`. And I would assume `Collectors.toSet()` sufficient. There is no need for a guaranteed `HashSet`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I've fixed that. But can we be sure that the set returned by `Collectors.toSet()` supports hashing?

Comment: We can be sure that the JRE developers will not change it to something worse just for fun or in other words, we can expect that `toSet()` will return a reasonably efficient `Set` implementation. It doesn’t have to use hashing, e.g. very small sets may perform better than `HashSet`. `Collectors.toSet()` allows the JRE to pick the best, i.e. future versions may return immutable sets being better prepared for even faster lookup than the mutable `HashSet`…

Comment: @Holger Agreed, let's trust the JDK guys, then. Thank you for all your feedback not only in this answer but also in the others.